# element-wise concatenation of string vectors

Tags: r

Say I have two character vectors:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")
b <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

How do I merge them such that I get:

```
ab <- c("a1", "b2", "c3")
```

Comment: @codoremifa: that's not at all the same question!

Comment: A bit of googling would have gotten you `paste`. The linked question tells you enough about the function to be able to use it for your problem.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `paste` or `paste0`:

```
> a <- c("a", "b", "c")
> b <- c("1", "2", "3")
> paste0(a, b)
[1] "a1" "b2" "c3"
>
```